# NSAutoLayout issues with vertical compression in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, size-classes, autolayout

I am messing around with Autolayout in Interface Builder using Size Classes in Xcode 6. Preview view shows me previews at different devices and they are look almost ok:
[image]
 Also there is no warnings at debug panel.
But compiling this I'm getting:
[image]
The same on real devices.
I what I don't understand, if things went wrong, why preview mode show that everything is ok? So the question is more: why is so difference between preview and compiled stuff and also: what can cause such a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode drives me crazy.
Compiling one more time, and everything is fixed by itself. Things I **didn't** made:

- manipulating constraints
- clean project
- delete derived data
- reset Simulator
- restart Xcode
- reload laptop

After half-hour of pulling hair it's just fixed by itself.